# Incrementing pointer to static allocated array

Tags: c, pointers, static-allocation

By how much is pointer **incremented** in these situations and why?

```
void f(int a[])
{
    a++;
    printf("%d", *a);
}

void g(int a[][M])
{
    a++;
    printf("%d", *a[0]);
}
```

Lets say that in `main` I have a **static allocated** array with **n** elements and **static allocated** matrix (*2D array*) with **n** rows and **M** columns and I'm calling functions **f** and **g** (*I couldn't write this in code because I was unable to post the question with a lot of code and almost no text*).

Comment: A pointer is a pointer is a pointer. When you increment a pointer using pointer arithmetic, it increments by an even amount of the byte size of the data type that it is pointing at.  You cannot increment an array, but `int a[]` decays to `int *a`, so `a` increments in `sizeof(int)` steps. `int a[][]` decays into `int **a`, so `a` increments in `sizeof(int*)` steps.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think in the second example the parameter is *adjusted to* `int (*)[M]`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau There is no array-to-pointer *decay* going on here. **Array parameters** are silently *rewritten* by the compiler to **pointer parameters**. There is absolutely no difference between `void f(int a[])` and `void f(int * a)`. The signatures are completely equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the both cases the pointers are incremented only once.:)

```
a++;
```

Their values are changed by the sizeof of the types of objects they point to. So the value of the first pointer is changed by `sizeof( int )` and the value of the second pointer is changed by `sizeof( int[M] )`
Take into account that parameter `int a[][M]` is adjusted to `int ( *a )[M]`

Thus within the functions the both pointers will point to second elements of the arrays. For the two-dimensional array its element is one-dimensional array. And this statement

```
printf("%d", *a[0]);
```

will output the first element (integer) of the second "row" of the two-dimensional array.